# Eloquent ORM relationships one-to-one or one-to-many?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I see the power of using Eloquent but have yet to put it to good use in my project. With two tables I want to achieve this:

```
//output - LinkedIn
echo User::find(42)->SocialProvider->Name
```

I have a user table and I have a SocialProvider table with a list of social sites with their name and api key info.

Record 42 in my user's table has a column 'SocialProviderID' with the the id of the LinkedIn record in my SocialProvider table.

I have defined the relationships in model classes as following

```
class User extends BaseModel implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'dbo_RegisteredUser';
    protected $primaryKey = "UserID";

    public function SocialProvider() { return $this->hasOne('SocialProvider','id'); }
```

AND

```
class SocialProvider extends Eloquent  {

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'dbo_SocialProvider';

public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('User','SocialProviderID'); }
```

But the queries and results are not executing as I'd like.

Does anyone have an ideas?

I'm using MSSQL but in my more familiar MYSQL, I would like this ORM scenario to perform a join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo_RegisteredUser
LEFT JOIN (dbo_SocialProvider)
             ON (dboRegisteredUser.SocialProviderID=dbo_SocialProvider.id)
WHERE dbo_RegisteredUser.UserID=42
```

Thanks

Jon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I figured it out with a bit of debugging. I specified the relationships incorrectly.

In my User model I needed

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    public function socialProvider() { 
        return $this->belongsTo('SocialProvider','SocialProviderID'); 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well...relationships use the ID of the model in question....and you're not referencing the actual user anywhere...

You need to have a collumn in the social Provider table that stores the `user_id`

Then in your functions...

```
public function SocialProvider() { return $this->hasOne('SocialProvider','user_id'); }
```

and...

```
public function user() { return $this->belongsTo('User'); }
```

Comment: Hmm, I think maybe the cause of the problem is that I haven't defined the relationship properly. Each user has just one social provider (LinkedIn, Facebook) so the Foreign Key constraint is user.SocialProviderID and that is a direct map to SocialProvider.id

With that said, the SocialProvider should have no relationship to a user. Only the user should reference a social provider (with user.SocialProviderID)

Comment: Well then the first thing that I see right off the bat, is you aren't extending Eloquent.....in the first class....you're only extending BaseModel.....but I come from Laravel3 so it might be completely diff in L4.

Comment: Yep it is a valid point. But from Base Model I extend Eloquent. If I directly extend Eloquent, I still get an empty result. thx though..

Comment: I believe these are backwards.  `public function socialProvider() { return $this->belongsTo('User','SocialProviderID'); }` and `public function user() { return $this->hasOne('SocialProvider'); }`